# Can't make two independent jar files using intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, package

I have a project structure which has 2 packages in it, say com.example.A and com.example.B which have dependencies. Now, I need two **independent** jar files for these two packages. How do I achieve this? I've tried creating different manifest files for these different packages and created artifacts using these manifests and was able to get two jar files. But they had the same content. I need the first jar, say jar_A, to only contain files from com.example.A package and second jar, say jar_B, to contain files from com.example.B package. How can I do this? Note that they are in the same project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve it with IntelliJ IDEA artifacts build system is by using 2 separate modules for these packages. In the artifacts configuration you can build 2 different jars from 2 different modules.

If it's not an option, you will have to use some Ant/Maven/Gradle custom scripts to filter out the output basing on package name to produce different jar files.